# Building Matlab and /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, mex

I try to use mex some toolbox using matlab. But I got these errors: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran`

I used Ubuntu 14.04. I installed `gfortran`. Could any one help ?

this is the output of : `ldconfig -p | grep fortran`

```
xiaoma@laptop:~$ ldconfig -p | grep fortran
    libhdf5hl_fortran.so.7 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5hl_fortran.so.7
    libhdf5_fortran.so.7 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_fortran.so.7
    libgfortran.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3
```

Comment: can you post the output of `ldconfig -p | grep fortran`?

Comment: @m.s.   hi, I have posted the output.